# XSS attack in title-tag angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

> for value `"><script>alert('xss');</script>`

Print value is coming fine because of ng-bind but for title I am not able to stop XSS scripting to run. Is there anything from angularjs like ng-bind for title tag too.

```
<span title={{name}} ng-bind="name">
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you strip html tags server side?

Comment: No alert for me. Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @Kevin as per requirement I need to show same data as he entered while creating.

Comment: @ Blackhole I have tried to create fiddle, but it seems it is not reproducible in fiddle.

Comment: @SanjayGupta Yea ok but codes must never be executed this way. At least convert html tags into html entities ( e.g `<` to `&lt;` ). If you're using PHP server side, you may want to use [**htmlentities()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)